# Redux async action time between requests keeps growing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, http, redux

I have an async action performing GET requests to Spotify's API just to see if the player is currently playing a song. I have the action on an interval so it runs every second. However after the first 200 requests (half of which are http option) or so the time between requests grows exponentially. Looking at the chrome devtools waterfall I see a burgeoning half-a-parabola. So is this -

1. My react/ redux functional component stopped running the code in the component and so the requests slow down considerably.
2. My interval is somehow adding onto itself because of re-renders?
3. Browser is throttling requests?
4. Other async requests are stopping this one from happening since all of my other requests use the async/ await syntax
5. Something else

EDIT

the action:

```
export const checkIfPlaying = (accessToken ) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await spotify.get(
      '/me/player',
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    )

    dispatch({
      type: CHECK_IF_PLAYING,
      playing: response.data.is_playing,
      song: response.data.item.uri
    });

  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(returnErrors(error));
  
  }
}
```

the component:

```
import React, {useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchElement } from '../../actions/elements';
import { getFilteredElements } from '../../selectors/elementSelectors';
import {checkIfPlaying} from '../../actions/spotify'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import ElementCard from './ElementCard';
import ElementDetail from './ElementDetail';
import FilterControl from '../FilterControl';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  cardGrid: {
    height: '90vh',
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  },

  list: {
    height: '100%',
    overflow: 'scroll',
  },

  filter: {
    marginRight: 14,
    marginLeft: 14,
    background: theme.palette.primary.light,
    borderRadius: '0 0 8px 8px',
  },
}));

const ElementList = ({ match }) => {
  const filteredElements = useSelector(getFilteredElements);
  const elements = useSelector((state) => state.elements);
  const element = useSelector((state) => state.elements[match.params.id]);
  const accessToken = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user.spotify_info.access_token);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let intervalId = setInterval(() => {dispatch(checkIfPlaying(accessToken))}, 1000)

  useEffect(() => {

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
  }, [intervalId])
  const classes = useStyles();
  let transitionDuration = 50;

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    dispatch(fetchElement(id));
  };
  const renderFilter = 
  Object.values(elements).length > 0 ? <FilterControl objectType='elements' attributes={Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.values(elements)[0])} /> : null

  const renderedList =
    Object.values(elements).length > 0
      ? Object.values(filteredElements)
          .sort((a, b) => (a['song'] > b['song'] ? 1 : -1))
          .map((element) => {
            transitionDuration += 50;
            return (
              <ListItem key={element.id} dense>
                <ElementCard element={element} transitionDuration={transitionDuration} handleClick={handleClick} />
              </ListItem>
            );
          })
      : null;


  const renderDetail = () => {
    return element ? <ElementDetail  element={element} /> : null;
  };

  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.cardGrid}>
      <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.filter}>
        {renderFilter}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={4} className={classes.list}>
        <List>{renderedList}</List>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={1}></Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.list}>
        {renderDetail()}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={1}></Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default ElementList;
```

Comment: Please show some actual code :) Can't give a meaningful answer without seeing what the code is in the first place.

Comment: Understood, just thought it might be some general thing about async functions and timeouts. Code added.

Comment: figured it out, answering below.